# insert when a particular record not found

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a situation that need to insert only if record does not exist. Normally, I'm going to use 2 queries with conditions like this:

```
SELECT FROM TABLE ->
    IF RECORD NOT FOUND THEN -> INSERT INTO TABLE
    ELSE -> DO NOTHING
```

I feel my solution is not a good one. How can I achieve the same thing with just a single query? For example:

```
SELECT * from user where status='A' AND name='Lewis'
IF RECORD NOT FOUND THEN
INSERT INTO user(status,name) VALUES('F','Lewis');
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like:

```
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from user where status='A' AND name='Lewis') 
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO user (status, name) 
        VALUES('F','Lewis')
    END
END
```

This works in SQL Server, and should be possible in MySQL as well.

Edit:

Apparently it's not working in MySQL (just testd). However, you could use `INSERT IGNORE`:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO user2 (status, name) 
    VALUES('F','Lewis');
```

Note that that would only work if you have a unique or primary key.

Another way could be to have the same unique or primary key, and then use:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO user2 (status, name) 
    VALUES('F','Lewis')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status=status;
```

This avoids ending up with other errors being ignored, and only ignores the duplicate key warning.